# How to get an UIImage out of an MWPhoto object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, mwphotobrowser

I'm using an open source [photo browser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) and it uses `MWPhoto` objects to display images instead of just `UIImage`. Everything works fine, except when I try to get the `UIImage` back out of an `MWPhoto`. It seems like there should just be a `.image` or `.getImage` method that would return the original `UIImage`... but there doesn't seem to be. Am I missing something? Or will I have to modify the library with an additional getter?

I mainly need this because I need to be able to compare two `MWPhoto` objects... but there is not a useful way to do this, so I figure comparing the `UIImage` of `MWPhoto` objects is the second best thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually image property is private so you have to make it accessible by removing the image property declaration from MWPhoto.m and write into MWPhoto.h.

In   MWPhoto.h

```
....
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL isVideo;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
....
```

Now you can access like photo.image //photo is a instance of MWPhoto

Comment: Ah, that is the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Sorta embarrassing, but I don't have enough reputation points to change the votes on a post yet :( Sorry mate, will do once I gain a few more.